# How to set all one column's default values to 0?

Tags: javascript, workflow, document-library, jsom

I have a document library in our site. 
I have a column and I want to set the column's default value to 0 at first.

But it is empty. My column is integer column that stores numbers.

How can I do this ?

Comment: Are you not able to set the default value from list settings?

Answer (score 1):

Follow below steps:

1. Go to Library.
2. Go to `Library Settings` from top ribbon option `LIBRARY`.
3. Scroll down to the column name for which you want to set the default value and click on column name.
4. Scroll down again, at the bottom side you will see the default value option.
5. Set the default value to 0(See below image for reference).

[image]

Comment: Try this and let me know if it works for you?